# Iterating Back to beginning of List C#

Tags: c#

Perhaps i'm Missing something in my implementation, or my understanding.

So i have a set number of elements for a list, specifically in this case 7, and i need to get information from a set pattern of those elements.

The interesting thing, is the Elements actually feasibly repeat forever, so instead of creating a list of 14, or 21 etc   elements, i figured there was a way to do it with 7.

for example,

```
LinkedList<string> list = new LinkedList(); 
list.add(); etc........
string combinedElements;    

for(int i = 0; i < list.Length; I++)
{
   combinedElements += (list.ElementAt(i) + list.ElementAt(i + 2) + list.ElementAt(i+4))
}
```

So you can see this would give an Array out of bounds exception, but how would i be able to implement this in a way that it would just loop back through the elements of the list, instead of me instantiating a list that has 21+ elements that are just repetitions of the same thing over and over?

for instance if the list was filled with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. i would want it to get every other element(twice), for every element. so i'd want it to return 1,3,5 2.4.6 3.5.7 4.6.1 5.7.2 etc

I tried searching everywhere, even through my C# books, but couldn't find anything on iterating back through a list or array without resetting loop.

Thanks in advance for any advice anyone can give.

Comment: it just looks like you're getting odd numbers of elements.. in which case dont i++, but i+=2..

Comment: You are trying to access items "i+2" and "i+4", when i=3 it will raise an out of bounds exception.

Comment: @Zalomon if you read the question, Gary says he's aware it causes an out of bounds exception.

Comment: Try the `%` operator: `list.ElementAt(i%list.Length)`

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for something along the lines of `list.ElementAt((i+2)%list.Length)`?

Comment: Hey thanks the Modulo worked! as soon as you guys put that answer i instantly remembered that how i shouldve done it. Thank you guys so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @UnholySheep, it is better to use modular function for this like

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
string combinedElements = "";
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
  {
     string currentSet = (list.ElementAt(i) + "," + list.ElementAt((i + 2) % list.Count()) 
                              + "," + list.ElementAt((i + 4) % list.Count()));
     Console.WriteLine(currentSet);
     //combinedElements += currentSet + " ";
  }
```

Comment: [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) is a property not a method

Comment: @UnholySheep, if you are using List, then it property as well as function

Comment: See the source for [List<T>.Count](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646) lines 137 and 1050